# Issue with MRTK

Tags: hololens, mrtk, windows-mixed-reality

Wondering if anybody else has run into this issue.  I'm working on a HoloLens application using Unity 2019.4 and Microsoft's MRTK 2.7.2.  I get the following messages when running on the device:

```
Loading native plugins
  Loading MicStreamSelector.dll
  Loading Microsoft.MixedReality.SceneUnderstanding.dll
  Loading pdfrenderer.dll
  Loading GpuStats.dll
  Loading AudioPluginMicrosoftSpatializer.dll
  Loading AudioPluginMsHRTF.dll
  Loading PlaneFinding.dll
  Loading Microsoft.MixedReality.Input.dll
Plugins: Failed to load 'Microsoft.MixedReality.Input' because one or more of its dependencies could not be loaded. 
(Filename: C:\buildslave\unity\build\Runtime/Misc/Plugins.cpp Line: 247)

Plugins: 2nd attempt to load module with '.dll' extension manually appended ('Microsoft.MixedReality.Input.dll') also couldn't be found (or it's dependencies). 
(Filename: C:\buildslave\unity\build\Runtime/Misc/Plugins.cpp Line: 253)
```

Shortly after those messages, I get an exception, which seems to be related, as it contains a bunch of stuff about Microsoft.MixedReality.Input:

```
COMException
  at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR (System.Int32 errorCode) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at WinRT.WinrtModule.GetActivationFactory (WinRT.HString runtimeClassId) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at WinRT.ActivationFactory`1[T]..ctor () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceMono (System.Boolean nonPublic) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor (System.Boolean publicOnly, System.Boolean skipCheckThis, System.Boolean fillCache, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark& stackMark) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance[T] () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at WinRT.WeakLazy`1+<>c[T].<.ctor>b__2_0 () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Func`1[TResult].Invoke () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at WinRT.WeakLazy`1[T].get_Value () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at WinRT.ActivationFactory`1[T].ActivateInstance[I] () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at Microsoft.MixedReality.Input.MotionControllerWatcher..ctor () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.WindowsMixedReality.Input.WindowsMixedRealityDeviceManager.Enable () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.BaseDataProviderAccessCoreSystem.Enable () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Input.MixedRealityInputSystem.Enable () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.MixedRealityToolkit+<>c.<EnableAllServices>b__70_0 (Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.IMixedRealityService service) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Action`1[T].Invoke (T obj) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.MixedRealityToolkit.ExecuteOnAllServicesInOrder (System.Action`1[T] execute) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.MixedRealityToolkit.EnableAllServices () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
Rethrow as TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceMono (System.Boolean nonPublic) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor (System.Boolean publicOnly, System.Boolean skipCheckThis, System.Boolean fillCache, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark& stackMark) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance[T] () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at WinRT.WeakLazy`1+<>c[T].<.ctor>b__2_0 () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Func`1[TResult].Invoke () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at WinRT.WeakLazy`1[T].get_Value () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at WinRT.ActivationFactory`1[T].ActivateInstance[I] () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at Microsoft.MixedReality.Input.MotionControllerWatcher..ctor () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.WindowsMixedReality.Input.WindowsMixedRealityDeviceManager.Enable () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.BaseDataProviderAccessCoreSystem.Enable () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Input.MixedRealityInputSystem.Enable () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.MixedRealityToolkit+<>c.<EnableAllServices>b__70_0 (Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.IMixedRealityService service) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Action`1[T].Invoke (T obj) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.MixedRealityToolkit.ExecuteOnAllServicesInOrder (System.Action`1[T] execute) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.MixedRealityToolkit.EnableAllServices () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0
```

Anybody have any clue as to why Microsoft.MixedReality.Input.dll will not load?  Any idea what dependency might be missing?  Where would I find a list of the dependencies?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Could you provide more information about your developing environment? Such as the Project Setting and Build Setting of Unity, and the Building Property of Visual Studio. Generally wondering if there's a consistent way to reproduce this.

Comment: FYI I did get this resolved a while back, can't even remember the specific details, but there was some package I was missing.  But thanks for the response anyway.